# How to bind a bean's method with package in actionListener?

Tags: jsf, el, jsf-2.2, methodexpression

I am pretty much newbie to Java/JSF technology and I've been trying to do simple UIs to understand how things are going on in Java/JSF world.

Now I want to bind a ManagedBean's method with its package name to a CommandButton's actionListener.

Example:

**index.xhtml**

```
...
<h:commandButton actionListener="#{com.acme.myclass.MyMethod}" ...
...
```

**MyClass.java**

```
package com.acme;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped

public class MyClass {

    public MyClass() {
        // Constructor
    }

    public void MyMethod() {
        // Do some job
    }

}
```

I tried to bind the method as the given example above but the method is not called. Besides I don't see my packages in Netbeans's little autocomplete window. If I bind the method in **#{class.method}** format (as all given examples on the internet) it works.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Why do I need to do this?

While projects are getting larger and larger naming classes getting harder and harder. So, I think that same class names in different packages make life easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSF doesn't permit that kind of actionlistener binding, simple. The only semblance to what you have in the JSF world, is a standalone implementation of the [`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/event/ActionListener.html) interface, with which you can then supply a FQN:

```
  <h:commandButton>
       <f:actionListener type="com.you.YourActionListenerImpl" />
  </h:commandButton>
```

Where `YourActionListenerImpl` will be a class implementing `ActionListener` as mentioned previously

As to *why* you want to do this, I think you're overstating the cost of naming - it's not that hard. Massive, sprawling projects are getting along just fine (look at the Spring project for example) with the naming of Java artifacts.

Comment: Thank you kolossus. I think this is an advanced topic about ActionListener interface. I didn't see anything like your example. This is a really good starting point for me.